# Assertions or mockito verification reusability - line of error

Tags: java, junit, mockito, assertions

I have a very long test with Mockito and I want to reuse a verification method with different arguments so the test code is more clean and maintenable.
Like this.

```
@Test
public void aggTest() throws ParseException, IOException {

    mockDataLoader();

    // This several times with different dates or hours
    testProcessSamples("2018-01-01 00:00:00 UTC");
    // ...

    // Then verify:     
    verifyDL("HOUR", "OP_DIR", "01/01/2018 00:00:00;ROA_OP-IN-B;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;");
    verifyDL("HOUR", "OP_DIR", "01/01/2018 00:00:00;ROA_OP-OUT-B;2;2;2;;;2;2;;;;;;;;;;;;");
    verifyDL("DAY", "AGG_DIR", "31/01/2018 00:00:00;ROA_AGG_Z_IN;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;");
    // About 100 lines like this ...
    verifyDL("MONTH", "AGG_DIR", "01/01/2018 00:00:00;ROA_AGG_Y_IN;;;;;;;;ERROR;;;;;;;;;;;"); // Where the error actually is
    verifyDL("MONTH", "AGG_DIR", "01/01/2018 00:00:00;ROA_AGG_Q_IN;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;");
    verifyDL("MONTH", "AGG_DIR", "01/01/2018 00:00:00;ROA_AGG_M_IN;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;");        

    BDDMockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(dataLoader);
}


private void verifyDL(String gra, String type, String csv) {
    BDDMockito.verify(dataLoader).loadData( // Where JUnit thinks the error is
            BDDMockito.argThat(new ContainsCsv(csv)),
            BDDMockito.argThat(new MatchXml(gra, type)));
}
```

But then when it fails JUnit obviously will point to the `BDDMockito.verify(dataLoader).loadData` line as the point of error. I wish it was pointing to the actual line in the test, the invocation to `verifyDL`.

The full stack trace is there but I have to scroll after the actual value and look for the right stack layer every time instead of just clicking on a convenient place on my IDE to be taken to the point of error.

As you can see I already made my own matchers to make the verify code shorter but it still doesn't fit well on one line as the maintainability would require.

Is there a way to tell JUnit that verifyDL is a helper method and it should be excluded from the stack?

I would need something like macros to write less and it being transformed to the actual verification code.

**Test explanation:**

I am mocking a lower level service named dataLoader, then I run some things on a higher level processing some input files and deep under that dataLoader will be called several times.

After all of that I check that the calls to dataLoader contained the data they were expected to contain.

**Edit:**

I tried this approach but I still want to choose the parameters order in the test that is something I could do with a verifyDL helper method:

```
vDL().loadData(argCsv("31/01/2018 23:00:00;AGG_XXXX_OUT;2;2;1;;;2;1;;;;;;;;;;;;"), argXml("HORA", "AGG_DIR"));
vDL().loadData(argCsv("31/01/2018 23:00:00;AGG_Y_OUT;2;2;1;;;2;1;;;;;;;;;;;;"), argXml("HORA", "AGG_DIR"));
vDL().loadData(argCsv("31/01/2018 23:00:00;AGG_ZZZZZZZZZZZ_OUT;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"), argXml("HORA", "AGG_DIR"));
vDL().loadData(argCsv("31/01/2018 00:00:00;AGG_XXXX_OUT;2;2;1;;;2;1;;;;;;;;;;;;"), argXml("DIA", "AGG_DIR"));
vDL().loadData(argCsv("31/01/2018 00:00:00;AGG_Y_OUT;2;2;1;;;2;1;;;;;;;;;;;;"), argXml("DIA", "AGG_DIR"));
vDL().loadData(argCsv("31/01/2018 00:00:00;AGG_ZZZZZZZZZZZ_OUT;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"), argXml("DIA", "AGG_DIR"));     
vDL().loadData(argCsv("01/01/2018 00:00:00;AGG_XXXX_OUT;5;8;7;;;8;7;;;;;;;;;;;;"), argXml("MES", "AGG_DIR"));
vDL().loadData(argCsv("01/01/2018 00:00:00;AGG_Y_OUT;5;8;7;;;8;7;;;;;;;;;;;;"), argXml("MES", "AGG_DIR"));
vDL().loadData(argCsv("01/01/2018 00:00:00;AGG_ZZZZZZZZZZZ_OUT;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"), argXml("MES", "AGG_DIR"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest way is to just catch the exception thrown by Mockito and rethrow a new one with a more detailed message. Something like this....

```
@Test
public void execute_test(){
    verifyExecution("First test case","one", "two");
}


public void verifyExecution(String description, String parameter_one, String parameter_two) {
    try {
        BDDMockito.verify(mockedService).doIt(eq(parameter_one), eq(parameter_one));
    } catch (MockitoAssertionError e) {
        throw new MockitoAssertionError(String.format("Verification failed while testing case %s, with message:\n%s", description, e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

This adds the 'description' parameter to the message that Mockito generates. This way you get all the information that Mockito provides and add to that, the scenario that you are testing.

Comment: I couldn't find the class to catch as it's not an `Exception` but an `Error` so `catch (Exception e)` didn't get it in my attempts. Thank you. I might try that and manipulate the exception stack trace before rethrowing it.